# Omnetpp "imported NED type not found:'artery.envmod.World'"

Tags: omnet++

I am currently trying to build a prject in omnet++ that includes parts of artery (another omnet++ project). The problem is, that inside the .NED file at the import statement there is the error:
"imported NED type not found:'artery.envmod.World'"

I have already added the project folder to the referenzed projects in the properties section and the artery project is also open.

Does anyone has another idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing inet. Worked for some of mine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).